# includeStats in neo4j.rb

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I'm using neo4j.rb, and when I run

```
MATCH (a {name:'apple'}) SET a.flag = true
```

I'd like to get the response data, which would be along the lines of:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [],
      "data": [],
      "stats": {
        "contains_updates": true,
        "nodes_created": 0,
        "nodes_deleted": 0,
        "properties_set": 1,
        "relationships_created": 0,
        "relationship_deleted": 0,
        "labels_added": 0,
        "labels_removed": 0,
        "indexes_added": 0,
        "indexes_removed": 0,
        "constraints_added": 0,
        "constraints_removed": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

Instead, I get nothing--the object is blank, I suppose because I'm not asking for nodes to be returned, but want metadata on the query results.

There's a proposed solution here using py2neo ([py2neo return number of nodes and relationships created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050170/py2neo-return-number-of-nodes-and-relationships-created)), with `includeStats: true`, and I've also tried appending it to the address I'm using to run queries as `?includeStats=true`, which I saw somewhere else and resulted in a server not available error (response code 302 / RuntimeError) for me. Is there any solution for this using neo4j.rb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't keep the metadata when returning results in the `neo4j-core` gem.  It might be something that's easy to add.  Perhaps you could create an issue:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/issues

Pull requests are welcome, of course!